# Nested Pairs Exercise

Tags: idris

Working through the ch6 exercises of [Type-Driven Development with Idris](https://www.manning.com/books/type-driven-development-with-idris),

exercise 3 states:

> We could implement a vector as nested pairs, with the nesting calculated from the
>   length. For example:
>
> ```
> TupleVect 0 ty = ()
> TupleVect 1 ty = (ty, ())
> TupleVect 2 ty = (ty, (ty, ()))
> ```
>
> Define a type level function `TupleVect` which implements this
>   behaviour. Remember to start with the type of `TupleVect`. When you have
>   the correct answer, the following definition will be valid:
>
> ```
> test : TupleVect 4 Nat
> test = (1,2,3,4,())
> ```

Here's what I came up with:

```
TupleVectType : Nat -> (a : Type) -> Type
TupleVectType Z     _ = ()
TupleVectType (S n) a = (a, TupleVectType n a)

TupleVect : (n : Nat) -> a -> TupleVectType n a
TupleVect Z _     = ()
TupleVect (S n) a = (a, TupleVect n a)
```

I thought that it was sufficient, but, `MyTupleVect 4 Nat` is wrong:

```
*Exercises> TupleVect 4 Nat
(Nat, Nat, Nat, Nat, ()) : (Type, Type, Type, Type, ())
```

But, if I provide an actual value, i.e. not a `Type`, it returns:

```
*Exercises> TupleVect 4 True
(True, True, True, True, ()) : (Bool, Bool, Bool, Bool, ())
```

Please advise me on how to correct this `TupleVect` function to match the expected output.

It's not clear to me how to provide `TupleVect 4 Nat`, and then enumerate the `Nat`'s, but beginning at `1`, not `0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your definition of `TupleVectType` is actually what `TupleVect` should be. The exercise asks you to implement a function `TupleVect` which returns the **type** of *n*-ary tuple-represented vectors.

Your definition of `TupleVect` is an implementation of what is commonly called [`replicate`](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/blob/b3fdc3e2dc6256b9cb03e4cee89edb1dd97b081d/libs/base/Data/Vect.idr#L193) that takes a single `x : a` to a vector `repeat x : Vect n a` by replicating it *n* times.

In summary, with your definitions, the following typechecks as expected:

```
foo : TupleVectType 4 Nat
foo = (1, 2, 3, 4, ())
```

so I'd advise just renaming `TupleVectType` to `TupleVect`.